# Wrong values being copied into TPCircularBuffer

Tags: objective-c, audio, signal-processing, core-audio

I am having a bit of trouble with TPCircularBuffer.

When I print out samples directly from my callback’s buffer I see correct values, but once I copy them into the TPCircularBuffer they are incorrect.

Any ideas?

I have used TPCircularBuffer in a test app, and everything worked just fine.

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

These are the relevant parts of the code:

```
//  Declare and initialize TPCircularBuffer
TPCircularBuffer circularBuffer;
TPCircularBufferInit(&circularBuffer, 4096);

//  Callback stores signed integers in inBuffer->mAudioData.
SInt16 * buffer = (SInt16*) inBuffer->mAudioData;

int32_t availableBytes;

//  Each SInt16 is 2 bytes.
//  So, this should place 512 SInt16 values from the buffer
//  into the circularBuffer, right?
TPCircularBufferProduceBytes(&circularBuffer, &buffer, 1024);

SInt16 *ptr2 = TPCircularBufferTail(&circularBuffer, &availableBytes);
printf("Total byte size of buffer: %i\n", (int)availableBytes);
printf("circularBuffer[0] = %i\n", ptr2[0]);
printf("buffer[0] = %i\n", buffer[0]);
```

This is the printout:

```
Total byte size of buffer: 1024
circularBuffer[0] = -16384
buffer[0] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking so here's a quick example.

Initialization:

```
TPCircularBuffer tpBuffer;
int secondsOfBuffer = 8;
float sampleRate = 44100.0;
int bufferByteSize = secondsOfBuffer * sampleRate * sizeof(SInt16);
TPCircularBufferInit(&tpBuffer, bufferByteSize);
```

Writing to head:

```
int32_t availableBytes;
SInt16 *head = TPCircularBufferHead(&tpBuffer, &availableBytes);
int sampleCount = 1024;
for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    head[i] = i;
}
TPCircularBufferProduce(&tpBuffer, sampleCount * sizeof(SInt16));
```

Reading from tail:

```
SInt16 *tail = TPCircularBufferTail(&tpBuffer, &availableBytes);
int32_t availableBytes;
int availableSamples = availableBytes / sizeof(SInt16);
for (int i = 0; i < availableSamples; i++) {
    printf("%i\n",tail[i]);
}
TPCircularBufferConsume(&tpBuffer, sizeof(SInt16) * sampleCount);
```